# How to fix “Xcode 6 quit unexpectedly"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, object

every time when i try to increasing 'Height Constraint' xcode 6 quit unexpectedly,

Removed user data, turned off source control (as some posts suggested), no effect, still crashes (while showing Indexing... that never finishes). Even reinstalled xCode, without any effect, still says the same.

Did anybody fixed such an xCode?

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
Sending _userDidPressStepper: to <IBLayoutConstraintConstantEditingController: 0x7ff622d2eb50> from <NSStepper: 0x7ff61e4bdfa0>
ProductBuildVersion: 6A1052d
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-6250/InterfaceBuilderKit/AutoLayout/IBLayoutConstraintPropertyEditingController.m:17
Details:  Assertion failed: constraint == constraintToModify
Object:   <IBLayoutConstraintConstantEditingController: 0x7ff622d2eb50>
Method:   -modifyConstraintProperty:forEditedObject:withBlock:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7ff618c33660>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   
  0: Sending _userDidPressStepper: to <IBLayoutConstraintConstantEditingController: 0x7ff622d2eb50> from <NSStepper: 0x7ff61e4bdfa0>
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010f2689ea -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010e022d1f _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010e02300e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010e022f70 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x0000000117cb99c2 __98-[IBLayoutConstraintPropertyEditingController modifyConstraintProperty:forEditedObject:withBlock:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  5  0x0000000117cad018 -[IBLayoutConstraint(IBLayoutConstraintIntegration) ibModifyPropertyOfConstraintWithOptions:usingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  6  0x0000000117cb992a -[IBLayoutConstraintPropertyEditingController modifyConstraintProperty:forEditedObject:withBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  7  0x0000000117cb9c70 -[IBLayoutConstraintPropertyEditingController setConstraintConstant:forEditedObject:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  8  0x0000000117caae7b -[IBLayoutConstraintConstantEditingController _applyConstantUsingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  9  0x0000000117ab0e22 -[IBAutolayoutPropertyEditingController _userDidPressStepper:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 10  0x00007fff9c166cd7 _os_activity_initiate (in libsystem_trace.dylib)
 11  0x00007fff8fd50497 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
 12  0x000000010e58e270 __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke (in DVTKit)
 13  0x000000010e024032 DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 14  0x000000010e45867e -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
 15  0x00007fff8fd502c0 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] (in AppKit)
 16  0x00007fff8ff24c5f __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
 17  0x00007fff9c166cd7 _os_activity_initiate (in libsystem_trace.dylib)
 18  0x00007fff8fd98ddc -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] (in AppKit)
 19  0x00007fff90199e4f -[NSStepperCell _sendActionFrom:] (in AppKit)
 20  0x00007fff8ff25b39 __48-[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
 21  0x00007fff9c166cd7 _os_activity_initiate (in libsystem_trace.dylib)
 22  0x00007fff8fdb3391 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in AppKit)
 23  0x00007fff90199c69 -[NSStepperCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in AppKit)
 24  0x00007fff8fdb2139 -[NSControl mouseDown:] (in AppKit)
 25  0x00007fff902abf4f -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 26  0x00007fff8fd3650c -[NSWindow sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 27  0x000000010f28b54b -[IDEWorkspaceWindow sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
 28  0x00007fff8fce8096 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 29  0x000000010f0347f4 -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
 30  0x00007fff8fb74e98 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 31  0x00007fff8fb602d4 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 32  0x00007fff93d995c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)
```

crashing thread:/

```
Performing @selector(_userDidPressStepper:) from sender NSStepper 0x7ff61e4bdfa0
abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
constraint == constraintToModify
crash report:

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9576b282 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff92559b73 abort + 129
2   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010f2685c6 +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:assertionSignature:assertionReason:extraBacktrace:] + 1510
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010f268ba0 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] + 1169
4   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010e022d1f _DVTAssertionHandler + 367
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010e02300e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 407
6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010e022f70 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 249
7   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000117cb99c2 __98-[IBLayoutConstraintPropertyEditingController modifyConstraintProperty:forEditedObject:withBlock:]_block_invoke + 81
8   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000117cad018 -[IBLayoutConstraint(IBLayoutConstraintIntegration) ibModifyPropertyOfConstraintWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 463
9   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000117cb992a -[IBLayoutConstraintPropertyEditingController modifyConstraintProperty:forEditedObject:withBlock:] + 346
10  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000117cb9c70 -[IBLayoutConstraintPropertyEditingController setConstraintConstant:forEditedObject:] + 167
11  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000117caae7b -[IBLayoutConstraintConstantEditingController _applyConstantUsingBlock:] + 454
12  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000117ab0e22 -[IBAutolayoutPropertyEditingController _userDidPressStepper:] + 112
13  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff9c166cd7 _os_activity_initiate + 75
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fd50497 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 410
15  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010e58e270 __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke + 379
16  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010e024032 DVTInvokeWithFailureHint + 83
17  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010e45867e -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 335
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fd502c0 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ff24c5f __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke + 131
20  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff9c166cd7 _os_activity_initiate + 75
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fd98ddc -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 144
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90199e4f -[NSStepperCell _sendActionFrom:] + 104
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ff25b39 __48-[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:]_block_invoke + 219
24  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff9c166cd7 _os_activity_initiate + 75
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fdb3391 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 1318
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90199c69 -[NSStepperCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 129
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fdb2139 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 714
28  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff902abf4f -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:] + 12827
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fd3650c -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 368
30  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010f28b54b -[IDEWorkspaceWindow sendEvent:] + 159
31  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fce8096 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2238
32  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010f0347f4 -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] + 924
33  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fb74e98 -[NSApplication run] + 711
34  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fb602d4 NSApplicationMain + 1832
35  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff93d995c9 start + 1
```

please assist me how to fix the issue, Thx...

Comment: Which version of Xcode 6?

Comment: working  on  xcode 6.1

Answer (score -1):

did you developer account expired? I met this problem either today, yesterday, the project built under my account runs very well. and today I found my developer expired.