# Xcode6 quits unexpectedly

Tags: ios, xcode, git, osx-yosemite

I'm using Xcode6 on (OS X Yosemite). **XCode is primary tool for programming** in obj-c, swift and ios. W**hen i click on source control, it quits un expectedly**. Due to this issue, i'm facing much difficulty while committing my code

- Had solved this issue by disabling source control from xcode
  preferences, but i need to enable them as i do need that.
- I once solved it by removing .xccheckout file from my project's repo
  but at the moment i'm unable to find that as well. (i'm using GIT for source control purpose)

What's the proper solution for that? (without disabling source control in xcode6)

Comment: Xcode is tool for ios development. and i'm facing issue in that. According to me, this issue is causing too much problem in programming, so it can be answered by the experts of IOS domain.
  

:The following issues( posted on this site ) are also like mine. But my problem is not solved using these:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075940/how-to-fix-xcode-6-quit-unexpectedly
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905900/xcode-5-crashes-xcode-quit-unexpectedly

Comment: My XCode sometimes crashes too when trying to commit but most of the time it does work though..